# Jumping content when toggle jQuery button

Tags: jquery, filter, toggle, mixitup

when i toggle the filter "CM", in the 2nd, 3rd and 4th row, the content is jumping and I don't know why.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

        $('.filter_content').mixItUp({
            controls: {
                enable: false // we won't be needing these
            },
            animation: {
                enable: false
            },
            callbacks: {
                onMixLoad: function(){
                    $(this).mixItUp('setOptions', {
                        animation: {
                            enable: true,
                            duration: 400,
                            effects: 'fade',
                            easing: 'ease'
                        },
                    });
                }
            }

        });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ly2aj687/

Can you help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with mixitup but it seems like because you were applying mixitup to filter_content which wraps all the options it would push everything to the top.  Here I attached it to model and it will work but now onMixFail fires whenever a column doesn't have the object you're filtering for.  If you need to see which columns don't have that option then you can grab it in the onMixFail event by using state.$targets.context.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 // Initialize buttonFilter code

    buttonFilter.init();

    // Instantiate MixItUp

    $('.model').mixItUp({
        controls: {
            enable: false // we won't be needing these
        },
        animation: {
            enable: false
        },
        callbacks: {
            onMixLoad: function(){
                $(this).mixItUp('setOptions', {
                    animation: {
                        enable: true,
                        duration: 400,
                        effects: 'fade',
                        easing: 'ease'
                    },
                });
            },
            onMixFail: function(state){
                //fires when there are no matches
                console.log(state.$targets.context);
                console.log(state);
            }
        }

    });

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8k9sp3r/)

Comment: Thanks man, the onMixFail function is not important to me. Another problem now is, that if you press the filter CM, the single element in the 3rd row is kind of vibrating, but why?

Comment: @fr3d I'm not too sure but I think it has something to do with mixitup trying to move that item to the top of the container as the container is shrinking due to other items being filtered out.